# Bracha made on spoiled food

Tags: halacha, blessing, food

Someone made a bracha on a glass of milk. He drank a cheekful and immediately spit it out because it was spoiled.

Is he required to find another food requiring the same bracha (*shehakol* in this case) immediately, or was the initial bracha considered valid because his initial intent was to drink the food and the fact that it was spoiled "accidental" (*oness*)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Shulchan Arukh ([OC 206:6](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%95_%D7%95)) rules:

> נטל בידו פרי לאוכלו ובירך עליו ונפל מידו ונאבד או נמאס צריך לחזור ולברך אף על פי שהיה מאותו מין לפניו יותר כשבירך על הראשון.
>   *הגה: רק שלא היה דעתו עליו לאכלו* ‏
>   If he took in his hand a fruit to eat and blessed on it and it fell from his hand and was lost or made disgusting, he must bless anew [on further fruits] even if there were more of that kind of fruit in front of him. *GLOSS: So long as he did not intend to eat from [the extra fruit in front of him].*

Thus in your case, there is no point in finding more food as the original blessing on the milk wouldn't apply to it. It's just over. Say "Barukh Shem..." and move on.

Comment: Citing a necessity/BCP of reciting "_Baruch..._" would improve your answer.

Comment: @msh210 It's the next line in ShA. I didn't want to quote the whole paragraph about how to handle yourself if it falls at various points in the process of saying the blessing